# Using fa-app in Famo.us / Angular partials

Tags: famo.us

In the Famous examples, each partial.html starts with the fa-app

However, Famous documentation states that you should only (usually) have one Context in your Famous app.

Should each of my partials (pages) have an fa-app wrapper, or should I be transitioning between routes inside the fa-app?

Thanks!